# getInitialProps doesn't render on client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side-rendering

I'm trying to fetch data from my API server to use in my page, but I need SSR for SEO purposes.

So what I want here is:

Server Side Rendering: When a search engine visits a page.

Client Side Rendering: When user navigates different pages.

It should be noted that I use `next/link` for all of my links like so:

```
<Link href="/products/1/slug-goes-here">
    <a>Product A</a>
</Link
```

I have tried following methods **(NOT AT THE SAME TIME)** but either way, they just request the API server only on server side and never on client side.

**Note:** It takes way too long to respond, at least 15 seconds.

```
MyPage.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const data = (await getData({ id: context.query.id })).data;
    
    return { data };
}

// OR

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const data = (await getData({ id: context.query.id })).data;
    
    return { props: data };
}
```

Comment: You use both `getServerSideProps` and `getInitialProps`? I don't think it is supposed to be used like this. Maybe that is the problem. I think `getInitialProps` is even deprecated

Comment: @OneQ - Oh sorry if it sounded like I'm using both methods at the same time, I'll update my question to clarify that.

Comment: if you try your api request on postman or something else, does it take 15sec too?

Comment: @OneQ - No it takes less than a second. BTW I found the solution just now. I'll post it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated `next` from `12.0.4` to `13.1.2` and the first thing that happened was **Internal Server Error** caused by using `<a>` inside `next/link`.

So I removed `<a>` from every `<Link>` in my App and now everything works as expected.

It should be noted that in version `13.1.2` there is no need to use `<a>` inside `<Link>` to make the link visible to search engines.